# matplotlib - draw a nicer graph of this function (x*x*x) / (x*x - 3*x + 2)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize the graph of this function with matplotlib.

`f(x) = (x*x*x) / (x*x - 3*x + 2)`

This function has a pretty interesting properties and graph.

It has as vertical asymptotes the lines `x=1` and `x=2`.
Also, it has another asymptote `y=x+3` which `f(x)` approaches
as `x` tends to plus and to minus infinity.

It has a local maximum at `3-sqrt(3)` and local min at `3+sqrt(3)`.

But the graph looks very ugly because the scale on the Y axis
is produced way larger than the scale on X axis. I guess that is
because the function is not defined for `x=1` and `x=2`.

See a (slightly) better graph here:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*x*x+%2F+%28x*x+-+3*x%2B2%29+

How can I make this graph look nicer with matplotlib?
Or... is this not possible and I should use some other library instead?

Here is my code.

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = -7
b = +7

x = np.linspace(a, b, 5000)
y1 = ( x*x*x ) / (x*x - 3*x + 2)

plt.plot(x, y1, color = 'red')

plt.show()
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT:**

**Here I am trying to tell matplotlib to not plot anything in the intervals
`(1-EPS, 1+EPS)` and `(2-EPS, 2+EPS)`. Still, it keeps plotting there. Why?!**

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = -10
b = +10

EPS = 0.1

x1 = np.linspace(a, 1-EPS, 2000)
x2 = np.linspace(1 + EPS, 2 - EPS, 2000)
x3 = np.linspace(2 + EPS, b, 2000)
x = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y1 = ( x*x*x ) / (x*x - 3*x + 2)
y2 = (x+3)

ax.plot(x, y1, color = 'red')
ax.plot(x, y2, color = 'green')

# plt.plot(x, y1, color = 'red')
# plt.plot(x, y2, color = 'green')

plt.axis([a,b,-100,100])

ax.grid(True, which='both')

ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')

plt.axvline(x=1, color = 'green')
plt.axvline(x=2, color = 'green')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure that the axis have the same scale using

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

Before the `plt.show()` line.

---

Try this then instead:

```
plt.axis([a,b,-100,100])
```

You can manually change the x and y limits to what you disire.

---

If you want to avoid the line between the positive and negative "infinite" values, you can, instead of ploting the function as a continous line, plot it as a series of dots using:

```
plt.plot(x, y1, '.', color = 'red')
```

This is however not as nice looking.

Another alternative is to split the array of values in into multiple parts and then plot them one by one.

---

**A final solution:**

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = mt.acos(mt.sqrt(11.0/12.0))

a = -3.5
b = +3.5

# a = -1.5
# b = 1.5

x = np.linspace(a, b, 5000)
y1 = ( x*x*x ) / (x*x - 3*x + 2)
# y2 = x * x

dy1  = np.diff(y1)
pos = np.where(abs(dy1) > 1000)[0] + 1
plot_y1 = np.split(y1, pos)
plot_x = np.split(x, pos)

print(pos)

for x_line, y_line in zip(plot_x, plot_y1):
    plt.plot(x_line, y_line, color = 'red')

plt.grid()
plt.axis([a,b,-100,100])
plt.show()
```

It now instead finds where there are large differences and splits up the array automatically.

Comment: Hm... this makes things even worse. Try it please.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's somewhat better. But why are the vertical asymptotes also drawn in red as if they are part of the function graph?

Comment: Well they are a part of the function? In this case they are not the asymtotes of the function, they are a part of it? That is why its called an asymptot, becouse the function will converge to it, i.e follow it.

Comment: Oh sorry nevermind, i missread you question. Python will plot the function coordinate by coordinate, and since the negative and positive points are next to each other in the array of points, there will be a line between them.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Your code works better now. Why is my second attempt not behaving as I expect? See my edit please where I use `concatenate` and I compose `x` to be the union of 3 intervals. Still no luck.

Comment: Well if you concatinate, it will still be a continous line since it is a  continous array of points.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can trick it with a large number of points to be plotted with no line between them:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100000)
def f(x): 
    return x**3/(x**2-3*x+2) 
plt.plot(x, f(x), '.', ms=1) 
plt.xlim(-10,10) 
plt.ylim(-20,25)
```

[image]

Or, if you don't want too many points in you plot, you can define `x1 x2 x3` intervals where there is no discontinuity, and plot them separately with lines (`plot(x1, f(x1), 'k-')`, `plot(x2, f(x2), 'k-')`, etc.). This is similar to what you do, but do not concatenate them in a single `x`.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it.